# WPF how to set the background of a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Hi I have an issue I have a combobox with which i cna select a color.

```
<ComboBox Name="cb_farbe" Text="farbe" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionChanged="FarbeSelected">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Name="rectangle_farbecontent"  Width="425" Height="20" Fill="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <SolidColorBrush>Blue</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush>Green</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush>LightBlue</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush>Black</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush>LightGray</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush>Gray</SolidColorBrush>
    </ComboBox>
```

What this does is provide me with a dropdown selection of differen colors. However when i select one the combobox just displays the hex string of the color. I have tried using other answers i found online but none of them worked what im currently trying to do  is the following. It stilld oesnt work though.

```
private void FarbeSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BrushConverter conv = new BrushConverter();

        cb_farbe.Background = (Brush)conv.ConvertFromString(cb_farbe.Text) as SolidColorBrush;
    }
```

Comment: Don't set the Text property. What exactly do you want to display?

Comment: @Clemens I want it to just be filled with a color instead of displaying the string after the user has selected a color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `IsEditable` and `Text` properties.

And don't change ComboBox properties in a SelectionChanged handler. Use an appropriate DataTemplate instead.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="425" Height="20" Fill="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <SolidColorBrush>Blue</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>Green</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>LightBlue</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>Black</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>LightGray</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>Gray</SolidColorBrush>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I already told that in the other answer. Use SelectedItem or SelectValue and SelectedValuePath.